# How to explode a list into new columns pandas

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have the following df

```
  x
1 ['abc','bac','cab']
2 ['bac']
3 ['abc','cab']
```

And I would like to take each element of each list and put it into a new row, like so

```
  abc bac cab
1  1    1  1
2  0    1  0
3  1    0  1
```

I have referred to multiple links but can't seem to get this correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: kindly share the source code : ``df.to_dict()``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) + [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
out = df['x'].str.join(',').str.get_dummies(',')
```

`out`:

```
   abc  bac  cab
0    1    1    1
1    0    1    0
2    1    0    1
```

Or with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) then [`groupby max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df['x'].explode()).groupby(level=0).max()
```

`out`:

```
   abc  bac  cab
0    1    1    1
1    0    1    0
2    1    0    1
```

---

Can also do [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) after `explode` if want counts instead of dummies:

```
s = df['x'].explode()
out = pd.crosstab(s.index, s)
```

`out`:

```
x      abc  bac  cab
row_0               
0        1    1    1
1        0    1    0
2        1    0    1
```

*Note output is the same here, but will be count if there are duplicates.

---

DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [['abc', 'bac', 'cab'], ['bac'], ['abc', 'cab']]
})
```

Comment: sorry, I simplified the example for the sake of the question. my strings are of multiple characters, so when I run this code there is a column for each character. I am looking for a column for each item of the list. See edit in my question.

Comment: I don't understand code still works. Updated with new sample data but none of the code blocks have changed.

Answer (score 1):

I will do

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

s = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['x']), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
```